# Why is b0VIM 9.0 is in my Mac Terminal PATH

Tags: macos, unix

I recently noticed that this is in my mac $PATH variable.  Does anyone know why or what it is? A little googling indicated that the name `b0VIM` is a VIM swap file.  Why would it be in my mac path? Is this concerning?

```bash
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:b0VIM 9.0
```

Comment: Your shell sets this when starting, either from its startup file (.bashrc/.zshrc depending on your shell) or from /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/* . Once you found it you can savely remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is is?**

Likely a mistake. Does that file actually exist anywhere? It's only adding a file called exactly that as something your shell might try to execute. That's pretty unlikely to happen.

`find . -name 'b0VIM*'` will find that file, if it exists.

I included the wildcard in case the `9.0` is part of that. Not clear where that came from either.

**Why would it be in my mac path?**

Because your profile picked up a mistake somewhere. Guessing a mistake in echoing to path.

**Is this concerning?**

Not if you find it and remove it, and unlikely to be anything more than a mistake as is.

**How to clean it up**

You can see everywhere in your home directory that setting your path doing something like the following (from my own $HOME):

```
    ➜  grep -r 'export PATH' $HOME
./.zshrc:# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
./.zshrc:export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
./.zshrc:export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

The `-r` there will recursively search subdirectories. That's a little extreme, but if you have your shell profile files referencing other files it'll find it.

`grep 'export PATH' $HOME/.*` is likely just fine.

Then just edit the file.

You don't mention which shell you're using, but since the default is zsh, let's use that. You can start a new shell in debug mode using `zsh -x` in your terminal and then that'll show you as it evaluates your profile files and builds your $PATH variable, eg.

```
+/Users/alex/.zshrc:63> export PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/'
```

Comment: It's not in the base mac path for sure.  It might be getting added by one of the brew apps I have installed.  I just wanted to know whether someone else is experiencing this.

I have done a `sudo find / -name 'b0VIM*'` and did come up with anything